# Half of <a> Links Not Visible, Appears Related to Position:Fixed?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Some of the links in my nav bar do not function. They seem to get covered up by an iframe element, and do not change color.

The iframe element is visibly below the nav bar, but I used .wrapper1 to reposition the iframe element.  When I remove the iframe element, or remove the .wrapper1 object, the problem disappears (the links work).

insight?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

.wrapper1 {position:fixed; left:50%; top:80px;}

iframe {
background: rgba(256,256,256,0);
position:relative;
top:60px;
left:-400px;

}
ul {
width:800px;
position:relative;
left:-50%;
list-style: none;
background: none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

li {
background:none;
display:inline;
width:100%;
padding-left:40px;
color:#FFF;
font-size: 16pt;
font-family:'Rammetto One', cursive;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color:#FFF;
}

a:hover, a:active {
color:#333;
}
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#000">

<div class="wrapper1">

<ul>
<li><a href="introduction.html" target="content_frame">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html" target="content_frame">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.html" target="content_frame">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="contact-us.html" target="content_frame">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div>



<div class="wrapper1">
<iframe name="content_frame" width="800" height="300"></iframe>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/UNbru/) (jsFiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to "ul" like so:

```
ul {
    width:800px;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Link to Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwEFh)

Comment: Thanks you!!! It works.  It's interesting, because they are not visibly overlapping...but I guess "fixed" allocates the original space, even if it is moved by "relative"!

Comment: For me when messing with z-index it's a lot of trial and error until it works right :p Please mark the answer as "correct" if it solved your problem :)